# Ordered Triple Notation Clarification involving the Ordered Pair Property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on a proof that involves the Ordered Pair Property and Ordered Triples and the notation used in the proof is $\langle x,\langle y,z\rangle\rangle$.

Can this ordered triple notation also be written as $\{\{x\},\{\{y\},\{y,z\}\}\}$? I have yet to see that notation used.

Thank you!

Comment: What is *Fundamental Theorem of Ordered Pairs* - it doesn't come up on Google ?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the Ordered Pair Property. I will make the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\langle u, v \rangle = \{ \{ u \}, \{ u,v \} \}$, then your formula is wrong:

$$ \langle x, \langle y, z \rangle \rangle
= \{ \{ x \}, \{ x, \{\{y\}, \{y,z\}\}\} $$

If you're simply conjecturing a way to realize ordered triples, your formula isn't good:

$$ \langle \{ s \}, t, t \rangle = \{ \{ \{ s \}\}, \{\{t\}\} \} $$
$$ \langle \{ t \}, s, s \rangle = \{ \{ \{ t \}\}, \{\{s\}\} \} $$

The left hand sides are different, but the right hand sides are the same set.

Comment: Ok. I see the error. I had a feeling my notation was incorrect. Thank you for your help.